# Differential of a map and linear independence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In the article *On the Lagrange-Dirichlet converse in dimension three*, Definition 2.7 says:

> A sequence $y_1, y_2, ... , y_m$ of real analytic functions on some
> neighbourhood $W$ in $M$ is a **strong regular sequence** if the map
> $(y_1, y_2, . . . , y_m) : W \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$
> is, in differential geometric terms, regular, that is to say the differential of the map at every point in $W$ is surjective.
>
> Explicitly, $y_1, y_2, ... , y_m$ is a strong regular sequence if at every point $p$ in $W$, the differentials $d_p y_1, d_p y_2, \dots , d_p y_m$ constitute a linearly independent set in $T_p W^\star$.

I thought of doing an example in $\mathbb R^3$ to better understand the definition. Taking for example

\begin{align} f_1(x, y, z) & = x + y + z, \\ f_2(x, y, z) & = x^2 + 2y - z \\ f_3(x, y, z), & = xy + 2y + 3z, \end{align}

I have
\begin{align} df_1(x, y, z) & = dx + dy + dz, \\ df_2(x, y, z) &= 2xdx + 2dy - dz, \\ df_3(x, y, z) &= ydx + xdy + 2dy + 3dz\end{align}

Then $(d_p f_1, d_p f_2, d_p f_3)$, a linear map from $T_p W$ to $T_{(f_1(p), f_2(p), f_3(p))} \mathbb R^3$, would look like

$$(dx + dy + dz, 2x dx + 2dy - dz, ydx + xdy + 2dy + 3dz).$$

Is this right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this paper. However, everything you've written looks right to me. (Apologies if I made a mess of editing - it turned out fiddlier than I expected.)

Comment: Anyway, in this example your $(f_1, f_2, f_3)$ would be regular iff $\det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2x & 2 & - 1 \\ y & x + 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \neq 0 $ for all $(x, y, z) \in W$.

Comment: ^ or, what amounts to the same thing, one can compute the wedge product $df_1\wedge df_2\wedge df_3$ and check whether or not it vanishes